# Eclipse CDT generated getters / setters name

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, generated-code

Is there a way (either via the UI, or in config files) to change the names of the C++ getters/setters generated by Eclipse CDT from the Java-style `getSomething()` to the more C++ like `something()` ?

Comment: +1: Didn't know about the getter/setter generation before!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now possible via the following menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's absolutely no way to do that currently, as *get* and *set* prefixes are hard-coded in *Generate Getters/Setters* wizard code.

Comment: It has been a few years. Has been fixed in eclipse in the latest release?

Comment: @DogEatDog few years late, but yes, see my answer.